# Y label shape for time_distributed lstm

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, lstm, keras-layer

The shapes of my data (samples, window, number of features):

```
X_train (3620, 3, 43)  
y_train (3620, 1) 
X_test  (905, 3, 43)   
y_test  (905, 1)
```

This is my model:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(448, input_shape = (3, 43), activation = 'relu', 
                        return_sequences=True))) 
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate1))
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, activation = 'relu', return_sequences = True))) 
model.add(Dropout(dropout_rate2))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(64, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
                                activation = 'relu')))    
model.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(nOut, kernel_initializer = 'uniform', 
                                activation = 'linear', 
                                kernel_regularizer = regularizers.l2(regu))))
model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])

net_history = model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size = batch_size, epochs = num_epochs, 
                        verbose = 0, validation_split = val_split, shuffle = 
                        True, callbacks = [best_model, early_stop])
```

I get this error:

ValueError: 
Error when checking target: expected time_distributed_4 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (3620, 1)

My X_train is done using a moving window of 3. So 3 steps of X for every 1 y_train label. The error seem to be telling me my y_train should be (3620, 3, 1), did I read it right?

And if so, whats the logic here or the logic I should apply, because every 3 steps in X_train to 1 y_train, how do I change it to 3 steps to 3 y? so all 3 y is the same? Let me give an example so I explain myself clearly.

currently X_train =

[[[1, 2, 3 .....43]

[1, 2, 3 .....43]

[1, 2, 3 .....43]]

...

[[1, 2, 3 .....43]

[1, 2, 3 .....43]

[1, 2, 3 .....43]]]

currently y_train = 
[[1].....[3620]]

should y_train become the below for it to work? 
 [[[1],[1],[1]].....[[3620],[3620],[3620]]]

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hey anyone able to help me out on this?